# implement multiple payment gateways in codeigniter checkout?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, gocardless, bitpay

Can Any one suggest me how to implement **multiple payment gateways** in a single cart page in **codeigniter**. i would like to implement **bit pay**, **go card less**, and **pay pal**, i don't know how implement this any ideas???
and any implementation techniques also useful for my development. i have seen this kind of implementation in word press.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0bgp.png)

Comment: you can't implement multiple payments or gateways in a single request,

Comment: follow: https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-codeigniter/

Comment: this isn't a Codeigniter related question - if you understand how to do that in wordpress you certainly are able to implement that in CI too...

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create a different Library for each provider - potentially storing files in the third_party folder (and referencing with APPPATH). You can then load whichever library you need depending on the choice. See : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Answer (score -1):

You will need to add one button in cart page like "Check Out", after clicking this button give or show multiple payment options to customer like PayPal, Credit Card etc in other page.

And than system identify which button pressed by customer or user.Also you will need to create different library for all payment options.